# ¿Cómo puedo obtener de una query los UsuariosId que "Reserva" pero no "Entro" en menos de X tiempo?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Principalmente la tabla tiene las columnas `Sentido` y `UsuarioId`. ¿Cómo seria una query para saber que UsuarioId's tienen un registro con `Sentido=RESERVA` pero no tienen un registro de `Sentido=ENTRO` en menos de 'x' segundos. **(Es decir, reservo un lugar pero no fue enseguida)**.
La columna FechaHora es del tipo `timestamp`.

[image: Tabla de Movimiento]

Answer (score 1):

Bueno explicare una forma de como podrías hacerlo:

Separamos dos subconsultas, una para `RESERVA` y otra para `ENTRO`,

Reserva:

```
SELECT UsuarioId, FechaHora FROM Movimiento
WHERE Sentido = 'RESERVA'
```

Entro:

```
SELECT UsuarioId, FechaHora FROM Movimiento
WHERE Sentido = 'ENTRO'
```

Ahora comparamos éstas uniendolas y verificando el tiempo de 5 segundos entre `RESERVA` y `ENTRO`, finalmente agrupamos por id de usuario quedando el código de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT E.UsuarioId FROM (
    SELECT UsuarioId, FechaHora FROM Movimiento
    WHERE Sentido = 'RESERVA'
) R LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT UsuarioId, FechaHora FROM Movimiento
    WHERE Sentido = 'ENTRO'
) E ON R.UsuarioId = E.UsuarioId
WHERE E.FechaHora > DATE_ADD(R.FechaHora, INTERVAL '5' SECOND)
GROUP BY E.UsuarioId
```

Obteniendo en este caso lo siguiente:

```
+----------+
| UsuarioId|
+-----------
|2         |
+----------+
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Lo que buscaba era que no haya un registro "Entro" después de X segundos de un "Reserva", no desde el tiempo actual.

Comment: Bueno ya modifique mi respuesta, si no es el resultado que esperas, te pediría que adjuntes un ejemplo de la salida que esperas en tu pregunta me ayudaría mucho. ;)